# C# Store Public-Key X.509 encoded key in ANS.1

Tags: c#, public-key-encryption, x509, public-key

i am trying to implement an API. (https://www.loxone.com/dede/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/08/0903_Communicating-with-the-Miniserver.pdf)

When you go to Page 5 you will see under 2.b) that I need to store a public key in Format: X.509 encoded key in ANS.1.

The problem is I have no idea how to do this in C#...

Can anyone please help me with that problem :)

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example for the publicKey that I get:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC393RoCVFixg3cZicByw05GYqlIkmqfx1lylJqBaF7BMI/FffD5BBoFpFurj4N1pDdMF/QhBEj1Pb3XGOkrHFCinYc0lCMbSjreE+QPjmnWnZeaPd3mtBfdcTSF6hYH0regFU8nvFVgLsoBUCMjuhfsvuaW4sLylU6KhZ9hCqVQwIDAQAB-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm trying the same. The description in the PDF is very concise

Comment: no sorry, i did not try after a few more fails

Answer (score 1):

If you still need it after 3 years, you can use the following C# (.NET 6) method:

```
public static async Task<RSA> GetPublicKey(string certStr)
{
    string base64 = certStr;
    if (base64.StartsWith("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"))
    {
        base64 = base64.Substring(27);
    }

    if (base64.EndsWith("-----END CERTIFICATE-----"))
    {
        base64 = base64.Substring(0, base64.Length - 25);
    }

    var asn = new AsnReader(Convert.FromBase64String(base64), AsnEncodingRules.DER);
    asn = asn.ReadSequence();
    asn.ReadSequence();
    //string objectIdentifier = asn.ReadObjectIdentifier(Asn1Tag.ObjectIdentifier);
    //asn.ReadNull();
    var data2 = asn.ReadBitString(out int bitCount);
    asn = new AsnReader(data2, AsnEncodingRules.DER);
    asn = asn.ReadSequence();
    var modulus = asn.ReadInteger();
    var exponent = asn.ReadInteger();

    var rsa = new RSACng();
    rsa.ImportParameters(new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus =  modulus.ToByteArray(true, true),
        Exponent = exponent.ToByteArray(true, true),
    });

    return rsa;
}
```

Not the best and no error handling, but works.

Then you don't need an X.509 certificate, just this RSA object:

```
var aes = Aes.Create();
string s = ByteArrayToHex(aes.Key) + ":" + ByteArrayToHex(aes.IV);
var encData = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
s = "jdev/sys/keyexchange/" + Convert.ToBase64String(encData);
```

Probably you can implement the ByteArrayToHex yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to export this public key as X.509 encoded as ANS.1 which can be a .pem file.

From https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file/9717#9717 :

PEM on it's own isn't a certificate, it's just a way of encoding data. X.509 certificates are one type of data that is commonly encoded using PEM.

PEM is a X.509 certificate (whose structure is defined using ASN.1), encoded using the ASN.1 DER (distinguished encoding rules), then run through Base64 encoding and stuck between plain-text anchor lines (BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE).

You can use openssl to make a .pem file which is ANS.1 compliant.

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out ./cert.pem -keyout ./cert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, by "ANS.1" they meant "ASN.1" (Abstract Syntax Notation 1), and by "ASN.1" they meant "DER" (Distinguished Encoding Rules for Abstract Syntax Notation 1).

To convert your current PEM certificate into a "DER" certificate you either a) `openssl x509 -in cert.pem -out cert.der -outform der` or b) read the base64 string between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" and convert it to bytes (e.g. `Convert.FromBase64String`).